# Is there a substitute for the 'feature_format' library?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feature_format'
```

This occurs when I try to load some libraries.

```
import sys
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline
from feature_format import featureFormat, targetFeatureSplit
from verify import dump_classifier_and_data, test_classifier
```

I got the code from this link.

https://github.com/arjunchndr/Fraud-Investigation-on-the-Enron-Email-and-Financial-Dataset/blob/master/Fraud%20Investigation%20on%20the%20Enron%20Email%20and%20Financial%20Dataset.ipynb

When I do: `pip install feature_format`

I get this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement feature_format (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for feature_format
```

It seems like the library doesn't exist.  When I Googled this issue, I came up with almost nothing.  Has anyone used this library before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`feature_format` is from Udacity's "Introduction to Machine Learning" course, references to it are usually in projects done by people taking the class.

I don't believe it's published to PyPI or any other package repositories, but you can get the code from Udacity's GitHub page: https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects/blob/master/tools/feature_format.py

Comment: Oh, I see.  I never took a single course on Python.  I just read a whole bunch of books, made countless mistakes, and learned a few things in the process.  Still learning new things every single day.  Thanks!!